# fixed length look-behind in RegEx

Tags: ruby, regex, tasker

I'm trying to extract a number from a string. The string is randomized but must contain one keyword, let's say 'key', and a number. I want to extract the first number behind the keyword.

Below is a sample string:

`123samples45have'key'andnumber678and90`

So in this sample string, number `678` is required.

I write the expression like `(?<=key.*?)[0-9]+`, but it appears Ruby only support fixed length look-behind. Is there any other solution could solve this?

Comment: `s[/key.*?([0-9]+)/, 1]` or `s[/key.*?\K[0-9]+/]` will do.

Comment: Or `(?<=key)\D+\K\d+`.